# How to open a new file in a another tab instead of a new window in Atom editor?

Tags: linux, atom-editor

I have already an atom editor window open in my Linux and I try running the atom from the terminal to open another file:

```
atom /path/to/new_file.txt
```

Every time atom tries to open a new window, when opening a new file instead of opening a new tab in the currently open atom editor. Is there is a way to tell atom (via a config or something) not open a new window if there is an atom window already open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there is a way to tell atom (via a config or something) not open a new window?

```
atom -n false /path/to/new_file.txt
```

Where:

```
-n, --new-window Open a new window. [boolean]
```

Source [Open file/project from terminal / command line - features - Atom Discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/open-file-project-from-terminal-command-line/1305/9):

```
atom --help
Atom Editor v0.80.0

Usage: atom [options] [file …]

Options:
-d, --dev Run in development mode. [boolean]
-f, --foreground Keep the browser process in the foreground. [boolean]
-h, --help Print this usage message. [boolean]
-l, --log-file Log all output to file. [string]
-n, --new-window Open a new window. [boolean]
-s, --spec-directory Set the spec directory (default: Atom’s spec directory). [string]
-t, --test Run the specified specs and exit with error code on failures. [boolean]
-v, --version Print the version. [boolean]
-w, --wait Wait for window to be closed before returning. [boolean]
```

---

#### Does atom have rc file or global config so I can set this option as default there?

> Atom loads configuration settings from the `config.cson` file in your `%USERPROFILE%\.atom` directory.

However the `--new-window` option is not one of the configurable options.

Source [Basic Customization](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/)

Comment: Thanks. Does atom have rc file or global config so I can set this option as default there?

Comment: @motam79 Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can add the `-n false` command to `%APPDATA%/Local/atom/bin/atom.cmd`.

E.g., in the file change

```
"%~dp0\..\app-1.58.0\resources\cli\atom.cmd" %*
```

to

```
"%~dp0\..\app-1.58.0\resources\cli\atom.cmd" -n false %*
```